# How to implement casting for custom types?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Realm and I created a `User` model. User can sign up through the app. When he does, what I am trying to do is to `POST` my `User` instance.

Here is what I started doing:

```
let params = currentUser as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>
octoClient.post("/users", options: params) { (data) in
    // ...
}
```

What I am looking for is something like:

```
class User: Object {

    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var firstName = ""
    dynamic var lastName = ""
    dynamic var email = ""
    dynamic var phone = ""
    dynamic var postalCode = ""
    dynamic var state = ""
    dynamic var country = ""
    dynamic var city = ""
    dynamic var address = ""
    dynamic var category = List<Industry>()
    dynamic var birthday = NSDate()
    dynamic var password = ""
    dynamic var passwordConfirmation = ""
    let notifications = List<Notification>()
    dynamic var privateToken = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()

    func toDictionary() -> [String: AnyObject?] {
        // format current instance to wanted format
        return [String: AnyObject?]()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do something like `let params = currentUser.toDictionary()`? but want to cast?

Comment: So what do you want exactly? How to implement `toDictionary`?

Comment: I just wondered if there was a way to cast custom types instead of calling a method so it sticks to "native" behaviours.